# Connect to SQL Server 2019 on Azure VM from Client in on-premisses restricted network

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection, firewall, network-protocols

I have a SQL Server 2019 on Azure VM and I am trying to connect to it from clients behind on-premisses network firewall.

The connection string is as follows:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
SERVER=x.x.x.x,1433;
DATABASE=XXXXX;
UID=XXXXX;
PWD=XXXXX;
TrustServerCertificate=No;
Trusted_Connection=No;
```

I think the client network firewall is blocking connections on port 1433 and possibly others.

What i've tried so far with no luck:

> 1. Change the server configuration to listen also on port 14330
> 2. Try to connect through a VPN (the firewall doesn't allow the connection to the VN Gateway)

The connection works just fine when established directly from the Internet.
I don't have administrative privileges over the client machines.

Any help on how to overcome this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you directly connect the Azure VM in your on-premise network?

Comment: v13 is a few years old. Are you not using [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)?

Comment: I can´t connect directly the Azure VM  in the on-premise network - RDP is also blocked. I can't instal the ODBC driver 17 for SQL server on the client machines because i don't have administrative privileges on those PC's.